# Explain this code in K&R 2-1

Tags: c, floating-point, range

I'm trying to determine range of the various floating-point types. When I read this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float fl, fltest, last;
    double dbl, dbltest, dblast;

    fl = 0.0;
    fltest = 0.0;
    while (fl == 0.0) {
        last = fltest;
        fltest = fltest + 1111e28;
        fl = (fl + fltest) - fltest;
    }
    printf("Maximum range of float variable: %e\n", last);

    dbl = 0.0;
    dbltest = 0.0;
    while (dbl == 0.0) {
        dblast = dbltest;
        dbltest = dbltest + 1111e297;
        dbl = (dbl + dbltest) - dbltest;
    }
    printf("Maximum range of double variable: %e\n", dblast);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why author added `1111e28` at `fltest` variable ?

Comment: Why downvotes? What's wrong with this question ?

Comment: @HalimQarroum; Sorry, its but not a dupe.

Comment: Don't understand the code, or don't understand the value or something else? You get downvoted and/or closed if it's hard to know what the question is.

Comment: @david.pfx; It is clear that OP do not understand that why `1111e28` is added to `fltest`

Comment: @haccks: So exactly how did that make it any clearer?

Comment: @david.pfx; To me it is crystal clear :)

Comment: The code is fundamentally wrong.  Say `DBL_MAX == FLT_MAX` with a value about `1E+37`, certainly allowable by the spec and common in simple platforms that have `float` and `double` as the same 4-byte type.  The code reports "Maximum range of double variable: 0.0e00\n".  This code depends on _prior_ knowledge of the max value of a `float/double` to work.

Comment: @didierc Later if I have time or if someone else posts it - feel open to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loop terminates when `fltest` reaches `+Inf`, as at that point `fl = (fl + fltest) - fltest` becomes `NaN`, which is unequal to `0.0`.  `last` contains a value which when added to `1111e28` produces `+Inf` and so is close to the upper limit of `float`.

`1111e28` is chosen to reach `+Inf` reasonably quickly; it also needs to be large enough that when added to large values the loop continues to progress i.e. it is at least as large as the gap between the largest and second-largest non-infinite `float` values.

Comment: Good point about `1111e28` being chosen larger than `FLT_MAX*FLT_EPSILON`.

Comment: How `0.0` becomes `NaN` ? o_O

Comment: @haccks `inf - inf` results in NaN (in `fl = (fl + fltest) - fltest;`)

Comment: @PascalCuoq; Oops! Got it :)

Comment: Hmmm.  If `1111e28` is chosen based upon largest and second-largest non-infinite values, then what is the point of the code?  Just return the largest value.

Comment: @chux yes, it's not particularly good code, is it? If I was writing it I'd use repeated doubling rather than adding a constant value.

Comment: @ecatmur Agreed about the weakness of code in question.  Still your answer is good.

Comment: A good answer, but incomplete. You did not provide a cogent explanation for the specific value 1111e28 (as against something slightly smaller or larger), or how to determine whether it is optimal, or how to calculate an optimal value if it is not.

Comment: @david.pfx Unfortunately the `1111e28` or test increment value needs, in general, to be about `FLT_MAX*FLT_EPSILON` to `FLT_MAX*FLT_EPSILON*1.5`.  Big enough to affect the addition, but small enough to step through each `float` value.  So for this method  to well find the answer `FLT_MAX`, code needs to approximately know the answer and `FLT_EPSILON`.

Comment: @chux: Still not an answer. To be specific, why 1111e28 and not 1110e28 or 1112e28? Because it's a cute value? Or because it doesn't really matter?

Answer (score 4):

OP: ... why author added `1111e28` at `fltest` variable ?
A: [Edit] For code to work using `float`, `1111e28`, or `1.111e31` this *delta* value needs careful selection.  It should be big enough such that if `fltest` was `FLT_MAX`, the sum of `fltest + delta` would overflow and become `float.infinity`.  With round to nearest mode, this is `FLT_MAX*FLT_EPSILON/4`.  On my machine:

```
min_delta           1.014120601e+31 1/2 step between 2nd largest and FLT_MAX
FLT_MAX             3.402823466e+38
        FLT_EPSILON 8.388608000e+06
FLT_MAX*FLT_EPSILON 4.056481679e+31
```

`delta` needs to be small enough so if `f1test` is the 2nd largest number, adding delta, would *not* sum right up to `float.infinity` and skip `FLT_MAX`.  This is 3x min_delta

```
max_delta           3.042361441e+31
```

So `1.014120601e+31 <= 1111e28 < 3.042361441e+31`.

@david.pfx Yes. 1111e28 is a cute number and it is in range.

Note: Complications occur when the math and its intermediate values, even though the variables are `float` may calcuate at higher precsison like `double`.  This is allowed in C and control by `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` or *very* careful coding.

---

`1111e28` is a curious value that makes sense if the author all ready knew the general range of`FLT_MAX`.

The below code is expected to loop many times (24946069 on one test platform).  Hopefully, the value `fltest` eventually becomes "infinite".  Then `f1`  will becomes NaN as the difference of Infinity - Infinity.  The the while loop ends as Nan != 0.0.  @ecatmur

```
while (fl == 0.0) {
    last = fltest;
    fltest = fltest + 1111e28;
    fl = (fl + fltest) - fltest;
}
```

The looping, if done in small enough increments, will arrive at a precise answer.  Prior knowledge of `FLT_MAX` and `FLT_EPSILON` are needed to insure this.

The problem with this is that C does not define the range `FLT_MAX` and `DBL_MAX` other than they must be *at least* `1E+37`.  So if the maximum value was quite large, the increment value of 1111e28 or 1111e297 would have no effect.  Example: `dbltest = dbltest + 1111e297;`, for `dbltest = 1e400` would certainly not increase 1e400 unless `dbltest` a hundred decimal digits of precision.

If `DBL_MAX` was smaller than 1111e297, the method fails too.  Note: On simple platforms in 2014, it is not surprising to find `double` and `float` to be the same 4-byte IEEE [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) ) The first time though the loop, `dbltest` becomes infinity and the loop stops, reporting "Maximum range of double variable: 0.000000e+00".

There are many ways to efficiently derive the maximum float point value.  A sample follows that uses a random initial value to help show its resilience to potential variant `FLT_MAX`.

```
float float_max(void) {
  float nextx = 1.0 + rand()/RAND_MAX;
  float x;
  do {
    x = nextx;
    nextx *= 2;
  } while (!isinf(nextx));
  float delta = x;
  do {
    nextx = x + delta/2;
    if (!isinf(nextx)) {
      x = nextx;
    }
    delta /= 2;
  } while (delta >= 1.0);
  return x;
}
```

`isinf()` is a new-ish C function.  Simple enough to roll your own if needed.

In re: @didierc comment

[Edit]
The precision of a `float` and `double` is implied with "epsilon": "the difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable in the
given floating point type ...".  The *maximum* values follow

```
FLT_EPSILON 1E-5
DBL_EPSILON 1E-9
```

Per @Pascal Cuoq comment. "... 1111e28 being chosen larger than FLT_MAX*FLT_EPSILON.", 1111e28 needs to be at least `FLT_MAX*FLT_EPSILON` to impact the loop's addition, yet small enough to precisely reach the number before infinity.  Again, prior knowledge of `FLT_MAX` and `FLT_EPSILON` are needed to make this determination.  If these values are known ahead of time, then the code simple could have been:

```
printf("Maximum range of float variable: %e\n", FLT_MAX);
```

Comment: Does not fully answer the question. Why 1111e28 and not (say) 1110e28 or 1112e28?

Answer (score 2):

The largest value representable in a `float` is 3.40282e+38. The constant 1111e28 is chosen such that adding that constant to a number in the range of 10^38 still produces a different floating point value, so that the value of `fltest` will continue to increase as the function runs. It needs to be large enough that it will still be significant at the 10^38 range, and small enough that the result will be accurate.

Comment: "largest value representable in a float is 3.40282e+38".  Commonly true when `float`  is a [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32).  But C does not specify this - the max value is implementation dependant.

Comment: Does not fully answer the question. Why 1111e28 and not (say) 1110e28 or 1112e28?

Comment: @chux: If the max value is substantially different, this code probably wouldn't work at all.

Comment: @david.pfx: 1111e28 looks arbitrary to me. It should probably work fine with 1110e28 or 1112e28.