# Is this comparison to floating point literal zero valid?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

From N3337 (C++11 draft) section 3.9.1.8:

> The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined.

Does this apply to any and all usage of a float type, regardless of if it is a literal or not? Here is the example that is causing me some concern:

```
float foo{0.0f};
if (foo == 0.0f)
{
    // Am I always guaranteed to get here?
}
```

If we assume that `0.0f` is not really true 0 as far as the implementation is concerned, but some undefined number, would this comparison still technically be valid since both operands were obtained via constants and even though I may not know its true value, they will both still be the same?

Equality comparisons with float literals like this always have a code smell and I just want to make sure there aren't certain use cases where this makes sense or is valid.

Comment: Note that the value representation of _integer_ types and _pointers_ are also implementation-defined.  And we'd definitely expect this to work for integers and pointers wouldn't we?

Comment: In the case yes. However floating point arithmetic suffers from rounding errors so you won't be guaranteed after having done operations on the float.

Comment: A whatever float(0) is equal to whatever float/integer 0 regardless of implementaion

Comment: Note that for your question, use of `0.0f` will behave _very_ differently than using `0.1`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17ae19cb3632e085

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, you're upcasting it to `double` first. Not sure if that's a fair comparison... If you compared against `0.1f`, it'd print `A`

Comment: If you're just checking to see whether something still has its initial value of 0.0, it's probably fine. If you're subtracting two things you think are equal and testing that against 0.0, you might think more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are guaranteed to get there. Float imprecision occures after processing operations on concerned numbers. Constants are safe in your case.

However, if you exceed floating-point number precision by providing too much decimals or you initialize the float with another data type, it might get interpreted differently.

For instance, this might not make it:

```
float foo{2.1234321f};
if (foo * 6.1234321f / 0.1234321f == 105.3428750f)
{
    // Am I always guaranteed to get here? Not at all.
}
```

If you want to be safe when comparing floating-point numbers, you should "approximate" the result. See the code below.

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class exact{};
class approx{};

template<class> struct tolerance;

template<>
struct tolerance<float>
{
    static constexpr float value() { return 0.00001; }
}

template<class T>
bool close_enough(T a, T b, exact)
{
    return a == b;
}

template<class T>
bool close_enough(T a, T b, approx)
{
    return abs(a - b) <= tolerance<T>::value();
}

template<class T>
bool close_enough(T a, T b)
{
    return close_enough(a, b,
        conditional<numeric_limits<T>::is_exact, exact, approx>::type{});
}

int main()
{
    float a = 2.1234321f, b = 105.3428750f;

    if (close_enough(a * 6.1234321f / 0.1234321f, b))
    {
        // Am I always guaranteed to get here? Yes!
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about "constants are safe".  If the `float` was initialized to the literal "0.1" and then compared to that same literal, it would fail.  It depends on how you define "constants" here.

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (foo * 24.0f / 0.5f == 24.0f)` or `if (foo * 6.0f * 2.0f == 24.0f)`?

Comment: Also, it's generally a good idea to implement a function that will accept a tolerance/distance between two float values, and to use the function when comparing two floats that aren't constant or if either float has a large number of significant digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @MooingDuck Can you explain why that would break? When I assign 100 to an int and then compare that int to 100 again, it would work, and that's the analogy people have been giving throughout the comments. So why does 0.1f not equal 0.1f?

Comment: @void.pointer: As long as the literals are all of type `float` and are not expressions, it's safe.  If the literals go through any kind of arithmetic or conversion, all bets are off, because floating-point-variables are all approximations.  two approximations of the same literal will always be the same, but when one goes through a different process than the other, inaccuracies can add up and cause them to differ.

Comment: Stupid example, working with exact representable (binary and decimal) floating points

Comment: @void.pointer `0.1f` will absolutely equal `0.1f` when dealing with literals. Notice that's not what MooingDuck said though. He's talking about initializing a `float` from a `double` literal (`0.1`) and then comparing it to a `double` literal.

Comment: Someone decided to introduce double into this discussion which is not only off topic but introduces a new level of complexity. However, I was thinking of the case where storing the literal (`0.1f`) in a variable requires the hardware to determine how to represent 0.1f, which may lose precision, so thus comparing it again against 0.1f may result in inequality. At which point would the hardware / implementation get involved (this is presumably the event that results in errors)?

Comment: @NicFoster Edited the answer to implement your idea.

Comment: Your `// Am I always guaranteed to get here? No.` is a terrible example, because you are always guaranteed to get there with binary floating-point that provides 2 bits of precision.

Comment: So I guess the general rule of thumb is that a float value does not become "binary" until non-constant operations are performed on the values? I assume the code does not utilize the hardware (which results in imprecision) until operations are performed at runtime. It's quite possible to have `constexpr` functions that do calculations on floats, right? Those would be potentially compile-time.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Well, thanks for the info. I edited the answer for your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know yes it is guaranteed to go to that block. As **0.0f** is a float constant.

```
float f = 0.0; /* OK, throw away bits to convert 0.0 from double to float */
assert ( f == 0.0 ); /* not OK, f is converted from float to double
   and the value of 0.0 depends on how many bits you use to represent it. */
assert ( f == 0.0f ); /* OK, comparing two floats, although == is finicky. */
```

Also note that in  `float x = 0` there is an implicit typecast from int to float.
And in `float x = 0.0f` we dont have such a typecast. And in `float x = 0.0` we have  an implicit typecast from double to float.

A good read: [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)

Comment: You went wrong when you said "the value of 0.0 depends on how many bits you use to represent it".  While that may be true for many values, 0.0 is exactly representable at any precision.  (So is `1.0`)

Comment: Actually, both asserts are not exactly OK: Theoretically the conversion of the double constant in `float f = 0.0;` could have changed the value. As such, it is neither OK to convert it back and compare it with the original constant, nor is it correct to compare it to a constant of type float since that might have been rounded differently. But the link is good :-)

Answer (score 0):

While there is technically very little guarantee in the standard about floating point numbers, CPUs only use two different representations for them: binary coded decimal, and [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Now the first one is rather esoteric, and never used by default because it provides less precision than the IEEE floats, so it is safe to assume that you have IEEE numbers whenever you have floating point.

Why is that important? Simply because the IEEE format guarantees precision for quite a few values. Specifically, it defines what `+0.0` and `-0.0` is, and it follows from the format specification that a `float` can represent all integers within the range `-16777216` to `16777216` exactly. (Likewise, the `double` format allows for the range `-2^53` to `2^53`, which is quite comfortable.) From this, you can make deductions about how long your calculations stay exact and hence allow for equality comparison.

However, whenever you use this information, you should also write a comment with your deductions, you can't assume that someone else will find them obvious...

Answer (score -1):

In practice

```
float foo = 0.0 ;
if (foo == 0.0)
{
}
```

tends to work. However, doing

```
float foot = SOMEARBITRARYCONSTANT ;
if (foo == SOMEARBITRARYCONSTANT)
{
}
```

may not work.

It tends to work when SOMEARBITRARYCONSTANT is a value that can be represented exactly and may fail otherwise.

I have seen the equivalent of:

```
float foo = 0.1 ;
if (foo == 0.1)
{
}
```

not work because the compiler rounded 0.1 differently.

In general, floating point == is a bad idea.

Comment: `foo == 0.1` **must** evaluate to false on a system that maps `float` to IEEE 754 binary32 and `double` to binary64, because then `(float)0.1`, the value of `foo`, is different from `0.1`, the value of `0.1`.